# Equation of string as hamiltonian field equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am using Hamiltonian field theory for the first time and I struggle with some final steps. The task is to derive the equation of vibrating string using [Hamilton's field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_field_theory). Here is what I have done so far:

Lagrangian density of vibrating string, denoting as usual $y=y(x,t)$ the displacement, $\rho$ the linear density and $T$ the tension:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\rho\left(\partial_t y\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}T\left(\partial_x y\right)^2
$$

Conjugate momentum fields are:

$$
\pi_{y_t} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_t y)} = \rho \ \partial_t y \ \ , \ \ \pi_{y_x} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_x y)} = T \ \partial_x y
$$

therefore:

$$
\mathcal{H} = \frac{\pi_{y_t}}{2\rho}+\frac{\pi_{y_x}}{2T}
$$

and here I am beginning to lose the ground. The problem are the variational derivatives $\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\mathcal{\pi_i}}$. I should give it a try, so:

$$
\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\mathcal{\pi_{y_t}}} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial \pi_{y_t}} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial \left(\partial_t \pi_{y_t}\right)} = \frac{\pi_{y_t}}{\rho} - 0
$$

Is this correct? How should look the term according to [the above quoted wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_field_theory#Equations_of_motion) (first line below the field equations on wiki)?

Comment: What is $\pi_{y_x}$? Usual Hamiltonian field theory does *not* associate momenta to the spatial derivatives, that is only done in the covariant approach known as [de Donder-Weyl theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Donder%E2%80%93Weyl_theory). In particular, you should not be taking $\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\pi_{y_x}}$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: OK, thanks, that's my mistake. So the hamiltonian density should be: $H=π2/ρ+(1/2)T(∂xy)2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you only need to introduce one conjugate momentum density:
$\pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{y}} = \rho \dot{y}$
The Hamiltonian density becomes
\begin{equation}\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2\rho}\pi^2 + \frac{T}{2}y_x^2\end{equation}

Next, the variational equations are:
\begin{eqnarray}\dot{y} = \frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta \pi} \\ 
\dot{\pi} = - \frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta y}
\end{eqnarray}

The first equation is trivial, i.e. $\pi = \rho \dot{y}$, and the second leads to the equation of motion. Using [the definition of the variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_field_theory#Equations_of_motion), we get 
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\pi} = -\frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial y} + \partial_x \frac{\partial \mathcal{H}}{\partial y_x} \\ 
 = 0 + T y_{xx}
\end{eqnarray} 
So 
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho\ddot{y} = T y_{xx}
\end{eqnarray}